# cannot add key to animation track in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

sorry to ask this dumb question again.
I was previously able to add a key to the animation track, but now I cannot add it the way I used to do.

[image]
I made an Enemy Placeholder object to my project and add the animation track. Then I hit the record button and right-click the Position in the transform section and hit add key. That was how I added keys to the Player rig but doesn't work for my Enemy placeholder...
I followed the Udemy course but now it doesn't work...

Can you see what I'm doing wrong in here?

### add this image later

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug where it won't record properly unless you're in the default layout. Select layout in the top-right and choose 'revert factory settings'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, jv. I added the image but can not figure out where the revert factory settings is...

Comment: @Yuuu Try Reset All Layouts.